# CSS Nav Element Hover With Bottom Border

Tags: css

I am trying to replicate the following effect : http://amplifiedvideodesign.com/capture.png

I can set the background color for hover but how can i do the border and the little arrow that are on the bottom?

Thanks.

Comment: Question starting with "I am trying to replicate the following effect" usually aren't for SO.

Comment: Umm, why not? I have a psd that a client gave me and i have to convert the design into wordpress. What is wrong with the question ?

Comment: Well, if you can set the `background-color` you can also set the `background-image` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the border you can just use the same code you just have to set a border and update its color. [You can try my example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJnUC/1/)

```
.tabs a:hover {
    background-color: #444;
    border-bottom-color: #484;
    color: #484;
}
```

As for the arrow/diamond/triangle whatever: That's something you can't setup that easily, but the easiest solution would be adding a background rather than using plain HTML/CSS.

Update: [Here's an animated example.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJnUC/2/)